# Nest Content inside ContentView

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't know if the title is clear enough, so let me explain what I am trying to do:

I have a `LoggingField` class which is composed of the following:

XAML:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Style="{DynamicResource LabelTitle}" x:Name="LabelTitle"/>
        <View x:Name="FieldContent"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

C#:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Field))]
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LoggingField : ContentView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Logging field.
    /// </summary>
    public LoggingField()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //
    // PUBLIC
    //

    // PROPERTIES

    /// <summary>
    /// The field's content.
    /// </summary>
    public View Field
    {
        set => FieldContent = value;
        get => FieldContent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The field's title.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        set => LabelTitle.Text = value;
        get => LabelTitle.Text;
    }
}
```

Page XAML:

```
<logcontent:LoggingField Text="Test Title:">
    <Entry Placeholder="PlaceholderText"/>
</logcontent:LoggingField>
```

From it, you can see that I want the `<Entry Placeholder="PlaceholderText"/>` to override the `<View x:Name="FieldContent"/>` object, but I can't make it work. It would always overwrite the entire ContentView, displaying only the placeholder `Entry`.

The only advancement I've made was adding `[ContentProperty(nameof(Field))]` in the ContentView's C# class, which made its original content be displayed but then the `Entry` object won't appear anymore.

So how can I make the `Entry` object correctly override the `View` object inside the ContentView? Thanks in advance.

PS: I've tried replacing `<View x:Name="FieldContent"/>` with `<ContentPresenter x:Name="FieldContent"/>` and using `ContentPresenter.Content` instead, but to no avail.

Comment: First, remove `[ContentProperty...]` attribute - in a ContentView, the entire contents is the ContentProperty; you definitely don't want just Field to be that; that would overwrite your entire StackLayout. In the linked answer, note `<ContentView x:Name="contentView" ... ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TealTemplate}">`That declares use of a `ControlTemplate`. And then define that template, as shown in linked answer.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is precisely what I needed, thank you! However, is it possible to make the `ContentView` object get the desired `ContentTemplate` from code instead of XAML? I see the `ControlTemplate={StaticResource TargetControlTemplate}` line repeating in every instance of that type, so I wonder if it's possible to default the object's `ControlTemplate` property to a value.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. Whenever you want something to be a default, you define a class (subclass the existing class) that has that default. Then you use that new class. Please make a new question that shows exactly the code you wish would work. Then someone can show you what to do.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to do it using a Style with a ContentTemplate setter. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `ControlTemplate` in code behind(viewmodel) , and bind it in xaml .

##### Code behind

```
ControlTemplate MyTemplate = new ControlTemplate(()=> {
      return new Entry { Placeholder= "PlaceholderText" };
});
```

##### Page Xaml

```
<local:LoggingField ControlTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}"/>
```

> However, this is total not recommended , the best way is to place `ControlTemplate` in xaml .

Comment: Thank you! However, I find myself repeating the same `ControlTemplate={StaticResource MyControlTemplate}` line every time I reference the `LoggingField` object in the page. Is there a way to assign the `LoggingField` object to a certain `ControlTemplate` by default?